# Logic based on output of a scalar function with BIT datatype

Tags: sql-server

I came across a stored procedure which does this:

```
DECLARE @DebugLogging BIT = dbo.fnIsDebugLoggingEnabled();

IF (@DebugLogging = 1) 
BEGIN
   -- some verbose logging information here...
END
```

based on whether a debug logging is enabled or not, which is an output given by scalar function `dbo.fnIsDebugLoggingEnabled()`.

I checked the create script for that function and I think it will always return 0. Maybe I am wrong. Can someone check if I am thinking correctly or not?

I am thinking --> why would someone put efforts to do something for a condition that will never occur?

Script for the function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnIsDebugLoggingEnabled]() 
RETURNS BIT 
AS  
BEGIN 
   RETURN 0; 
END
```

I ran `select dbo.fnIsDebugLoggingEnabled()` and it indeed returned 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct; the returned value will always be zero so the verbose logging will not occur.

I can't say why the developer chose to implement the debugging flag this way but it may be a deployment option where different versions of the function are created depending on the selection. Personally, I'd store configurable values like this in a table.

Comment: deployment option? is there any tool to create SQL objects with these scripts that is used by SQL developer for creating something like this? Can you give me some example?

Comment: @SunMan, there are many tools that may be used to deploy databases or it many have been done manually.